# Preview a printed page IE 8

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, printing, internet-explorer-8, print-preview

I'm trying to print part of a webpage.  To begin with, when I try printing [this](http://www.dos.ny.gov/coog/foil2.html), (from IE 8), only page one printes, without anything but the header.

To get around this issue, I tried printing setting the **page range** to the **selection** option, but didn't like how the page came out.  How can I preview what a printed page would look like, if I want to only print selected text?

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking on Page in the upper right.  Choose Style -> None.  After this, the page will become more plain looking. Now try a Print Preview.

My next idea would be saving the file "Save As" and choose Text. Then edit / print the text file.

Otherwise you may have better luck copying /pasting what you need into MS-Word.  Or try with another web browser such as Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: This helps, it adds 7 pages, making the total 8 pages.  Page one however doesn't change. Its still just the header, then a blank page.

You addressed my problem, but didin't answer the question.  Can you try answering how to view the preview print for a page range?